# How do I install Python modules on OSX if I don't have admin privs?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, ipython

I don't have admin privileges on my work computer (OSX) and do some light Python scripting (mostly web scraping). I don't have admin privileges at work and don't really want to learn OSX but I also don't want to lug my Ubuntu laptop around everyday just to write scrapers.

Is there a straightforward way for me to install modules without admin privileges? It seems like I need `sudo` to run `easy_install`. I can ask to have things installed, but I'd rather not have to ask every time I want to see if a module does what I need. FWIW, right now I just need `BeautifulSoup` and `csv`

Comment: I get around this at work by having a personal installation of python on a filesystem I do have privileges on, away from the default installation location. Is this possible? Although virtual environments are a typical work-around, I dont know anything about them, especially on OS-X

Answer (score 3):

Others have mentioned using virtualenv or pyvenv. That has its advantages, but if you want a quick and dirty solution, you can use the `--user` option to easy_install to install packages without admin rights. It installs it somewhere under your home directory.

http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/easy_install.html#use-the-user-option

Answer (score 2):

Just install `virtualenv` once, then work on local environments. It's a good practice too.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a per-user python installation using pyenv. You can then install modules without requiring any administrative rights.
https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv